# java hashcode and equals

Tags: java, hashcode

Create the hashCode and equals method for the following class.

```
private static class MyOb {

    private String name;
    private Integer quality;
    private final int MAXIMUM = 23;

}
```

I could not solve this question

Comment: are you trying to get your homework done?. Put some efforts first

Comment: hint: look at the source code of any java class e.g. Object

Comment: actually i was asked in the interview and i could not answer

Comment: Is it a `nested` class?

Comment: no it is not we just have to create hashcode and equals method

Comment: Did you get the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java class has default hashCode and equals method method implemented through super class. If u want to over ride them u can by following:

```
class MyOb {

private String name;
private Integer quality;
private final int MAXIMUM = 23;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((quality == null) ? 0 : quality.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    MyOb other = (MyOb) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (quality == null) {
        if (other.quality != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!quality.equals(other.quality))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

Note: **class cannot be private or static**

Comment: Why have you used MAXIMUM? It's just a constant

Comment: sorry changed accordingly thanks for remembering

Comment: Might be worth pointing out the eclipse generate hashcode/equals which I'm guessing you used.

Comment: yeah generated code using eclipse IDE,but my intention is  to let him know these are default methods and can be overridden

Comment: Inner classes can be `private` and/or `static` -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Yes it can be but I refered to normal class, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score -1):

if you want see hash code of class.
create object

```
    Myob myObject=new Myob();
    System.out.println(myObject);
```

if want to equals method

```
    myObject.equals(which one you want to campare);
```